# Unable to make scrollviewer scroll horizontally

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012, stackpanel

I have a ScrollViewer that contains a StackedPanel with rectangles laid out horizontally. I want to be able to scroll horizontally, but this isn't happening for me. Here is my XAML:

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage
    x:Name="pageRoot"
    x:Class="BlastSwing.GroupedItemsPage"
    DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    IsTabStop="false"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:BlastSwing"
    xmlns:data="using:BlastSwing.Data"
    xmlns:common="using:BlastSwing.Common"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>

        <!--
            Collection of grouped items displayed by this page, bound to a subset
            of the complete item list because items in groups cannot be virtualized
        -->
        <CollectionViewSource
            x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource"
            Source="{Binding Groups}"
            IsSourceGrouped="true"
            ItemsPath="TopItems"
            d:Source="{Binding AllGroups, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=data:SampleDataSource, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"/>
    </Page.Resources>

    <!--
        This grid acts as a root panel for the page that defines two rows:
        * Row 0 contains the back button and page title
        * Row 1 contains the rest of the page layout
    -->
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Back button and page title -->
        <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Text="Blast Swing" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}" Margin="40,0,-10,53"/>

        <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="628" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1366" RenderTransformOrigin="0.476999998092651,0.998000025749207" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" Margin="-22,0,0,0" HorizontalScrollMode="Auto">
            <StackPanel Height="568" Width="1313" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.0179999992251396,0.512000024318695" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Fill="#FF974B55" Height="568" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="371"/>
                <Rectangle Fill="#FF17179C" Height="568" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="371"/>
                <Rectangle Fill="#FF8D2B80" Height="568" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="371"/>
                <Rectangle Fill="#FF301D2F" Height="568" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="371"/>
                <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="568" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="371"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>

        <!-- Back button and page title -->

        <!-- Horizontal scrolling grid used in most view states -->

        <!-- Vertical scrolling list only used when snapped -->

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

            <!-- Visual states reflect the application's view state -->
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscape"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="Filled"/>

                <!-- The entire page respects the narrower 100-pixel margin convention for portrait -->
                <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait"/>

                <!--
                    The back button and title have different styles when snapped, and the list representation is substituted
                    for the grid displayed in all other view states
                -->
                <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="pageTitle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SnappedPageHeaderTextStyle}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Grid>
</common:LayoutAwarePage>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting Scrollviewer's Width="1366" which is more than your child stackpanel Width="1313".

If you want to see the horizontal scrollbar then you might want to set the size of ScrollViewer less than 1313 and it should be able to display the horizontal scrollbar as it is not able to display the content fully.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` property on the ScrollViewer to `Visible` or `Auto`.

Comment: I set it to Auto, but still no luck unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the Width of your StackPanel manually and it is less than the total of its children.